# How to set `Procfile` for a Mezzanine app deployed on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, mezzanine

I already have a Mezzanine app deployed on Heroku. The system ran OK before, but today the web page showed an error message `Internal Server Error`. Checked with `heroku logs` and found that the command `web python manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 1` is deprecated and Heroku suggests using `<projName>.wsgi:application`.

But Mezzanine currently has different project layout from Django (Mezzanine's `settings.py` is in the project root directory), so I tried the following in `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn wsgi --log-file -
```

However, such a setting results in error message:

```
ImportError: No module named 'app'
...
ImportError: Could not import settings 'app.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?) No module named 'app'.
```

Then I tried:

```
web: gunicorn <projName>.wsgi --log-file -
```

The error message (of course ;-):

```
ImportError: No module named '<projName>'
```

So, how do I set `Procfile` so that gunicorn is able to find the project's `settings.py` and `wsgi.py`?

Comment: Good question  ... May be the question should be `How to define Procfile when wsgi.py file also in same folder?`. Some try i end up with `web: gunicorn --pythonpath="$PWD/myproject" wsgi:application --log-file=-`  but really it's not working though ..

Comment: Can you please display your `wsgi.py`? IIRC this has something to do with there needing to be some kind of agreement between how the Procfile line specifies the wsgi call and how settings is called in `wsgi.py`.

Comment: I have to put the wsgi.py in the Answer for better examining.

Comment: It turned out that Mezzanine is about to roll out a new version which has the same project layout as Django's and it's already available. Check https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/issues/1250#issuecomment-112803085. So, my problem is sort of solved if I use the new Mezzanine. Others using old Mezzanine may still need a solution?